# Control begin and end point object between 2 points

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

im trying to move a object in unity between 2 points, and at the moment it kinda works strange, i read the documentation and it says that the object begin point is (0,0,0) so my object goes under my other mesh that i have there, and the end point i can actually control, in my case it is 10, i want the object to move between 1.5 and 10(not 0 to 10) 
**i have this**

```
void Update () {
    transform.position = new Vector3(transform.position.x,Mathf.PingPong(Time.time,10.0f), transform.position.z);
}
```

**when i try to put speed on the ball doing this:**

```
void Update () {
    transform.position = new Vector3(transform.position.x,Mathf.PingPong(Time.time,10.0f) * 10, transform.position.z);
}
```

the object does not colide and goes back at the end point it just stop looping and never came back how can i correct this 2 problems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your object has a collider, I suggest you move it via its Rigidbody rather than its Transform, to avoid potential collision issues. Try this:

```
public float MinY = 1.5f; // y position of start point
public float MaxY = 10f; // y position of end point
public float PingPongTime = 1f; // how much time to wait before reverse
public Rigidbody rb; // reference to the rigidbody

void Update()
{
     //get a value between 0 and 1
     float normalizedTime = Mathf.PingPong(Time.time, PingPongTime) / PingPongTime;
     //then multiply it by the delta between start and end point, and add start point to the result
     float yPosition = normalizedTime * (MaxY - MinY) + MinY;
     //finally update position using rigidbody 
     rb.MovePosition(new Vector3(rb.position.x, yPosition, rb.position.z));
}
```

Here you have a better control on the distance to travel, and the speed.
Actually I didn't get exactly what are the problem you faced. But don't forget here and in your try, that you are directly modifying the position of the object, not adding forces or else.

Hope that helps you.

Answer (score 1):

I think you simply misunderstood how the [`Mathf.PingPong`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.PingPong.html) method works :

- first argument **t** is the value you want to "clamp" between *0* and the given **length** : this is were you want to put the `Time.time` as you did since this value will increase over time and therefore perpetually oscillate. If you want to increase/decrease the oscillation speed you have to multiply it.
- second argument **length** is the max value of the "clamp" : if you want to increase/decrease the distance (in your case) you have either set it to *0* and multiply the whole `Mathf.PingPong(...)` by a value or directly give it the wanted value (both implementations will have a different effect.
- `Mathf.PingPong(Time.time * speed, 1.0f) * value` : **speed** will affect the oscillation speed / **value** will affect the max value reached AND the speed / time to complete the oscillation (back and forth) will remain the same as **value** changes and decrease as **speed** increases
- `Mathf.PingPong(Time.time * speed, value)` : **speed** will affect the oscillation speed / **value** will affect the max value reached BUT NOT the speed / time to complete the oscillation (back and forth) will increase as **value** increases and decrease as **speed** increases

About your other problems :

If you want to move your object between **1.5** and **10** you have to write something like this :
`transform.position = new Vector3(transform.position.x, 1.5f + Mathf.PingPong(Time.time, 10.0f - 1.5f), transform.position.z);`.

Also if you want to detect collision, avoid setting position manually as it will mess up with Physics and cause weird behaviors. Best way to move your object while keeping physic working is to do as @Heldap said using [`Rigidbody.MovePosition`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.MovePosition.html).